# How convert type from const char * to char *

Tags: c++, char

I'm trying create simple application in C++. This application has to read from file and displays data. I've written function:

```
std::vector <AndroidApplication> AndroidApplication::getAllApp(){
    std::vector<AndroidApplication> allApp;
    std::fstream f;

    f.open("freeApps.txt");
    std::string line;
    if(f.is_open()){
        while(getline(f, line)) {
            std::string myLine = "";
            char * line2 = line.c_str();
            myLine = strtok(line2,"\t");

            AndroidApplication * tmpApp = new AndroidApplication(myLine[1], myLine[2], myLine[4]);
            tmpApp->Developer = myLine[0];
            tmpApp->Pop = myLine[3];
            tmpApp->Type = myLine[5];
            allApp->pushBack(tmpApp);
        }
    }
    return allApp;
}
```

It throws me an error in line:

```
myLine = strtok(line2,"\t");
```

An error:

> cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'char *'

Could you tell me how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use strtok, you'll need a writeable copy of the string. c_str() returns a read-only pointer.

Comment: The real answer is not to use strtok, as Paul says, but if you really want to, make a copy of the string, for instance with strdup. But don't forget to free the memory when you're done!

Answer (score 11):

Don't use `strtok`.  `std::string` has its own functions for string-scanning, e.g., `find`.

Comment: @whiteangel: No. Why are you not using documentation? C's `strtok` functionality is widely documented across the internet, clearly explaining that it has quite complex behaviour that is _not_ the way you're assuming. (By the way, `split` in Python is deprecated.)

Answer (score 3):

You can't just "convert it" and forget about it. The pointer you get from `.c_str()` is to a *read-only buffer*. You need to copy it into a new buffer to work with: ideally, by avoiding using antiquated functions like `strtok` in the first place.

(I'm not quite sure what you're doing with that tokenisation, actually; you're just indexing into characters in the once-tokenised string, not indexing tokens.)

You're also confusing dynamic and automatic storage.

```
std::vector<AndroidApplication> AndroidApplication::getAllApp()
{

    std::vector<AndroidApplication> allApp;

    // Your use of fstreams can be simplified
    std::fstream f("freeApps.txt");

    if (!f.is_open())
       return allApp;

    std::string line;
    while (getline(f, line)) {

        // This is how you tokenise a string in C++
        std::istringstream split(line);
        std::vector<std::string> tokens;
        for (std::string each;
             std::getline(split, each, '\t');
             tokens.push_back(each));

        // No need for dynamic allocation here,
        // and I'm assuming you wanted tokens ("words"), not characters.
        AndroidApplication tmpApp(tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[4]);
        tmpApp.Developer = tokens[0];
        tmpApp.Pop = tokens[3];
        tmpApp.Type = tokens[5];

        // The vector contains objects, not pointers
        allApp.push_back(tmpApp);
    }

    return allApp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost works...but gives an error error C2039: 'pushBack' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>'

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the error is actually on the previous line,

```
char * line2 = line.c_str();
```

This is because `c_str()` gives a read-only pointer to the string contents. There is no standard way to get a modifiable C-style string from a C++ string.

The easiest option to read space-separated words from a string (assuming that's what you're tying to do) is to use a string stream:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::istringstream stream(line);
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream), 
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          back_inserter(words));
```

If you really want to use `strtok`, then you'll need a writable copy of the string, with a C-style terminator; one way to do this is to copy it into a vector:

```
std::vector<char> writable(line.c_str(), line.c_str() + line.length() + 1);
std::vector<char *> words;
while (char * word = strtok(words.empty() ? &writable[0] : NULL, " ")) {
    words.push_back(word);
}
```

Bear in mind that `strtok` is quite difficult to use correctly; you need to call it once for each token, not once to create an array of tokens, and make sure nothing else (such as another thread) calls it until you've finished with the string. I'm not sure that my code is entirely correct; I haven't tried to use this particular form of evil in a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for it:

Theoretically you could use `const_cast<char*>(line.c_str())` to get a `char*`. However giving the result of this to `strtok` (which modifies its parameter) is IIRC not valid c++ (you may cast away constness, but you may not modify a const object). So it might work for your specific platform/compiler or not (and even if it works it might break anytime).

The other way is to create a copy, which is filled with the contents of the string (and modifyable):

```
std::vector<char> tmp_str(line.begin(), line.end());
myLine = strtok(&tmp_str[0],"\t");
```

Of course as the other answers tell you in great detail, you really should avoid using functions like `strtok` in c++ in favour of functionality working directly on `std::string` (at least unless you have a firm grasp on c++, high performance requirements **and** know that using the c-api function is faster in your specific case (through profiling)).